# Почему вторая часть кода не работает($('.hide-filter') ...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.smart-filter-show-more-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).text('Скрыть все');
        $(this).addClass("hide-filter");
        $('.redcode-filter-index-col').fadeIn();
    });
    $('.hide-filter').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.redcode-filter-index-col').fadeOut();
        $(this).removeClass("hide-filter");
        $(this).text('Скрыть все');
    });
```

Comment: Наверное в опечатке. Выложите больше кода (HTML) и опишите хотя бы как должен работать данный код

Comment: Html покажите, что-ли

Comment: Есть кнопка показать все при нажатии появляются доп.блоки(верхняя часть) - я пытаюсь сделать(нижн) так чтобы при нажатии на неё потом блоки, которые появились - исчезали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка в том, что вы вешаете обработчик на `.hide-filter`, которых ещё нет, т.к. они "создают" после выполнения первой части кода.

Решение: использовать [делегирование событий](https://itchief.ru/javascript/jquery-handling-events#dobavlenie-sobytiy-k-dinamicheski-sozdannym-obektam):

```
$('.smart-filter-show-more-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text('Скрыть все');
    $(this).addClass("hide-filter");
    $('.redcode-filter-index-col').fadeIn();
});
$(document).on('click', '.hide-filter', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.redcode-filter-index-col').fadeOut();
    $(this).removeClass("hide-filter");
    $(this).text('Скрыть все');
});
```